# Change date in menu bar from "DAY MONTH" to "MONTH DAY"?

Tags: finder, calendar, menu-bar, internationalization, clock

The date in my menu bar is in "DAY MONTH" format (e.g. 23 Oct) but I want it in "MONTH DAY" format (e.g. Oct 23). How can I do this? Also, it shows "Tue" as the week day when I'd prefer seeing it in full (e.g. "Tuesday").

In System Preferences -> Language & Text, "Region" is set to "Custom" because I changed a few things on the page. Under "Dates", I see: "Thursday, January 5, 2012", "January 5, 2012", "2012-01-05", and "2012/01/05".

Is this date format based on my location and is therefore fixed? (I'm not in the US at the moment.)

I'm using Mountain Lion now, but I recall a few versions ago that it was much easier to modify the date/time appearance in the menu bar by copying and pasting a few elements in the Date/Time preference pane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this page on macyourself.com](http://www.macyourself.com/2008/08/31/modify-the-default-clock-in-os-xs-menu-bar-to-show-the-full-date/) - it does exactly what you're looking for, it seems.

Comment: This trick used to work, up until either Mountain Lion or Lion.

Comment: It seems to work on my Lion system. From what I read, in 10.8 you can find it at 'Date & Time' preferences > 'Clock'. Kind of a stab in the dark though, as I'm not running 10.8 here.

Comment: It's very likely that this was changed in Mountain Lion then. My "Date & Time" panel looks very similar to the one in Lion, meaning there's nowhere for some sort of text input where I could change the format to what I want.